# In NavigationDrawer ( gluon mobile ) Icon is not Visible

Tags: android, javafx, gluon, javafxports, gluon-mobile

I have created a Navigation-Drawer in my App using [NavigationDrawer](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/4.3.2/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/NavigationDrawer.html).
The icon is not visible in the [viewitem](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/4.3.2/index.html?com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/NavigationDrawer.ViewItem.html) in  my version of NavigationDrawer.
Here's the code...

```
Node getNavigation()
{

NavigationDrawer drawer=(NavigationDrawer)getDrawer();
NavigationDrawer.Header header =new NavigationDrawer.Header(
"Mobile App","Navigate through ...",
                new Avatar(21, new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/icon.png"))));
        drawer.setHeader(header);

        final Item primaryItem = new ViewItem("Primary", MaterialDesignIcon.HOME.graphic(), PRIMARY_VIEW, ViewStackPolicy.SKIP);

        final Item secondaryItem = new ViewItem("Secondary", MaterialDesignIcon.DASHBOARD.graphic(), SECONDARY_VIEW);

        drawer.getItems().addAll(primaryItem, secondaryItem);

    return drawer;
}
```

And Here's the ScreenShot below ...

[image: Navigation Drawer]

Comment: Does your app extend `MobileApplication`?

Comment: No It does'nt extend MobileApplication .it extends Application.

Comment: That's why you don't get the icons...

Comment: There should a way to get  the icon displayed without extending MobileApplication .right?

Comment: By not extending `MobileApplication` you are missing all the setup done in that class that is required later on, including GlassPane initialization to layout the Views, or adding the glisten CSS stylesheet, in turn responsible for the missing fonts and icons

Comment: where and how do I check those glisten CSS stylesheets and How does initialisation of ' View ' s are  Done Initially !

Comment: I told you before: those are the things, among others, that `MobileApplication` does for you when you launch your application.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for sharing this info,Sir. but, What is the solution to this problem

Comment: That you extend `MobileApplication`?

Comment: I mean: Obviously you can implement everything yourself. I did that in an app we were tasked to create (some custom design I had no idea of how to achieve with Gluon out of the box). But if you are happy with material design, then just use their framework. I, on the other hand, needed to spent hours and hours re-creating some basic sh#t. You don't want that.

Comment: you mean like using [Jfoenix](http://www.jfoenix.com/).Right? @dzim

Comment: JFoenix is fine, but I only used the dialog from it, so far. But again: if you are happy with material design, why don't u use Gluon's solution?